Git-hook to show if I've got a stash on the checked out branch
The following has happened a couple of time and I'm looking for an automated way to catch myself before I repeat the mistake. Solutions saying "just remember" or "just don't do that" won't be marked as correct.
Quite often, I'll be working on a git branch, have some uncommitted code, and quickly need to make a change to another branch. I use git stash to stash the uncommitted code, git checkout to swap to the other branch, I make and commit my changes, then I git checkout to the other branch. And hopefully, I remember to git stash pop. The problem is that I don't always remember, especially if I end up having to make a couple of changes on the other branch that end up taking a few hours/days.
Is there a git hook I can write that, when I checkout a branch that has a stash on it, will send me a little message? Something like:
$ git checkout foo
Switched to branch 'foo'
You have 1 stash on this branch, use `git stash pop` to unstash it.

It doesn't have to be fancy, but I think it'll save me a lot of headache. Answers like "just remember to run git stash list" won't be accepted.

I won't write a full answer suggesting aliases for doing/undoing temporary commits on the branch instead of stashing since you seem to want someone to just craft the Y in your XY problem. But this is a bad use of stash, imho.

I agree with @RomainValeri. If you make a temporary commit instead (like prefixed with “TEMP” or “WIP”) this work-in-progress state will be impossible to miss when you switch back.

I changed my mind and posted what I hinted at, feel free to disregard it but I think it can be useful to people with the same initial need to consider multiple options.

If this is a bad usage of stash, what's the intended usage? My use-case (interrupted workflow) is given as an example in the git stash docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-Interruptedworkflow

@beyarkay You're right about the use case example in the doc. I remember having started from this definition too. But as I tried to convey in my answer, the only pragmatic stash use case I've been able to identify after a few years is code deletion with the possibility of an afterthought. Use it to wipe uncommitted changes, it's better than a hard reset which doesn't allow regret.

If the answer is “just don’t do that”, I will send it back; if the answer is “just remember git stash list”, I will send it back

As branches may share the same commits in their histories, it's hard to say if a stash is related with a specific branch. We can use the hook post-checkout to remind you of the possible stash entries you may forget.
After we switch/checkout a branch, post-checkout is invoked. It receives 3 parameters: the previous head, the current head, and a flag indicating if it was a branch checkout or a file checkout. We can test some or all of the stash entries. If the current head is the first parent of a stash entry, we say the stash is on this branch.
#!/bin/bash

PREVIOUSHEAD=$1
CURRENTHEAD=$2
CHECKOUTFLAG=$3

if [[ "$CHECKOUTFLAG" -eq 0 ]];then
    # ignore a file checkout
    exit 0
fi

export IFS=:
git stash list | while read entry desc;do
    if [[ "$CURRENTHEAD" = $(git rev-parse "${entry}"^) ]];then
        echo "You have a stash on the current head:$entry:  $desc"
    fi
done

Here are some known issues I can think of. There are words like WIP on master or WIP on dev in the default stash description, but we do not use them in the hook. Multiple branches may refer to the same commit and a stash made on one of them can be applied to another head. Sometimes we may work on a detached HEAD which has no branch name and can also accept a stash apply. The hook just prints the remind messages as more as possible, which might be noisy.
Another issue is that if you don't maintain stash entries well, the stash entry list gets long, and the hook may take quite a time. You can test only the top N entries in the while loop.
The hook cannot report such a stash. Make a stash A on main, create a new commit and then make another stash B, switch to main to invoke the hook. As A's parent is not the current head, it's not reported. A further complicated case is that main has a number of diverged heads and stashes are made on them. Only the stashes related with the current head are reported. It's common when you do some experiments on the local branch and reset between these test heads. If you are also interested in these stash entries, the test in the while loop needs more codes.

An alternative solution to stashing: temporary commits.
As an example, let's take your typical scenario:

Quite often, I'll be working on a git branch, have some uncommitted code, and quickly need to make a change to another branch.

That's indeed a very common situation. But then you do:

I use git stash to stash the uncommitted code, git checkout to swap to the other branch, I make and commit my changes, then I git checkout to the other branch.

Let's change course at this point. Use stash only for snippets you want to delete but might need to inspect later in case of an afterthought.
For valid but unfinished code, don't stash, but commit instead. Use for this a couple of quick aliases:
git config alias.wip 'commit -am "WIP - DO NOT MERGE"'
git config alias.unwip 'reset HEAD~'

You have to change branch in a hurry? git wip and checkout elsewhere. When you change back to your branch, undo the temporary commit with your git unwip and resume work.
You'll get used to it very fast, and the stash will stay (what it should have been named) a paper bin. (Which, like the windows one, doesn't immediately delete things but let you inspect and restore recent enough deleted files, once in a while, if needed)

Is there somewhere I can read about your view on not using git stash like I'm using it? I'm unconvinced, but am open to a convincing argument against using git stash and for using WIP commits. WIP commits seem like you're just recreating stashes, but I'd like to see your side of the debate.

I love the spirit. I don't have a solid article especially focused on the topic, but a quick glance at google results had encouraging results. To answer your last point about recreating the stash, I'd say no for two reasons. One, with temporary commits you don't have to learn (and work around) the quirks and traps of git stash, and two your temporary code stays on the relevant branch, which is a big plus. It's local, it doesn't impact anyone since you'll never push these commits (or, in some cases, push them only on non-shared branches).
